# How can I interpolate unsorted 2D numpy arrays in Python and compare the interpolated values to the original one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate the mode coefficients of an SVD decomposition. I have a quadratic equation `ax^2 + bx`, with random `a` and `b`.  I then fill a matrix `y` the values of the quadratic, and then use `svd`. Now I need to interpolate the resulting coefficients of the first mode, given by `c1` in the code, for `a` and `b` between 0 and 1. I have tried many things over the last couple of days, but none is working, and the other questions on interpolation are not helping me. My interpolant gives exact `c1` values at the `a` and `b` and `c1` I specified, but nonsense at the other known `c1` values.

Also, how would I be able to check the `c1_interpolated` array for values at a specific `a` and `b`? i.e. `c1(a = 0.05, b = 0.08)` without calling the function every time?

I'd be very grateful for any help, since I've been stuck on this issue for several days.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


def f(x, a, b):
    return a*x*x + b*x + 1

end = 1.01
begin = 0
x = np.arange(begin,end,0.1)
npoints = int(1/0.1+1)

a = (np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints))
b = (np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints))
#c = np.random.uniform(0,1,npoints)

cols = 5

y = np.zeros((cols,a.size))

for i in range(cols):
        y[i] = f(x, a[i], b[i])

u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(y, full_matrices=True)


c1 = (vh[0])
c2 = vh[1]
c3 = vh[2]

sample  = 8
input_arr = list(zip(a[:sample], b[:sample]))

A= np.linspace(min(a[:sample]), max(a[:sample]))
B = np.linspace(min(b[:sample]), max(b[:sample]))
A, B = np.meshgrid(A, B)

interp = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(input_arr, c1[:sample], fill_value=0)

c1_interpolated = interp(A, B)
```

Comment: Why do you need to interpolate? Why can't you just evaluate the function at the points you are interested into and then do the SVD? And if you need to interpolate, can you better explain how the first row of vh is related to x, a and b?

Comment: Hi @Patol75 . The reason I need to interpolate is that this is really a 'test' program, into which I should be able to feed any matrix y, obtain a singular value decomposition, and interpolate the modes of the coefficients. As for why I need to do that:

Comment: I am working with the output of a program that takes a medical scan of a patient, and gives a dose distribution. The idea of this project is to see how the distribution changes if the input parameters are perturbed slightly, so that we can obtain the new dose distribution quickly without redoing the entire calculation. 

The singular value decomposition is described here: http://www.columbia.edu/itc/applied/e3101/SVD_applications.pdf

Comment: The U matrix of the decomposition contains the modes, the S contains the eigenvalues, and the V contains the weighting coefficients of those modes. We only have mode coefficients for certain a and b, but we want to interpolate the data to obtain them for all a and b. in a given range. The a and b are coefficients of a quadratic function, and x is just the grid the function is plotted on. These are not so important, though, as it just test data I made up to test the interpolating function. The coefficients of the modes of the decomposition depend on a and b.

Comment: I actually need to interpolate all rows of vh, but I just tried the first one so far.

Answer (score 0):

I will just try to sum up here what I have understood because this sounds extremely confusing.

You have a matrix. You are performing a singular value decomposition on it, which gives you back three arrays. You then wish to interpolate through the third array, which corresponds to the right-singular vectors of the matrix and is a set of orthonormal eigenvectors of the product of the hermitian of the matrix with itself. Not even asking how to perform this interpolation, what will it give you? If we consider the first row of your matrix, each of its elements is given by the product of the first row of the first array by the first element of the second array by each column of the third array. If you interpolate through the columns of the third array, this is going to give you a first row of the matrix with more elements. So why don't you just interpolate the matrx right away? I really do not understand what you want to achieve here...